# How to use private IP based backends with google cloud API gateway?

Tags: gcloud, api-gateway

So I am trying to make Google cloud's API gateway serve requests from a private IP based backend. Currently, the backend is a Kubernetes based service. However, I couldn't find it explicitly being mentioned whether its possible or not.

Has anyone else encountered such an issue given that its a pretty common use case? It seems possible only when the API gateway infrastructure has a link to the VPC network(route table) or an explicit private connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking for a while I think that the best way to do what you are asking is to use Private service connect, this allows private consumption of services across VPC networks that belong to different groups, teams, projects, or organizations and also lets you connect to service producers using endpoints with internal IP addresses in your VPC network.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-service-connect-apis#enable-private-google-access) is a guide of how to use Private Service Connect to access Google APIs.

the Google API gateways exist only for serverless product and is intended to be use only against serverless backends(s). It is possible to configure it against public IP’s that are hosted on our Google backends because they leverage the same x-google-backend configuration key-value pairs in the openapi.yaml for API Gateway, but more niche features like authorization on behalf of backend services, or limiting access to backed services hosted on non-serverless platforms like GKE are currently not supported. a possible workaround could be to set up endpoints directly with your GKE cluster you, this documentation could help you [first](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine#python), [second](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method), [third](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/endpoints/getting-started/openapi.yaml)

Best regards.

Comment: I researched on that, however could not get it to work.

Comment: can you tell me in what way did not work, did you get a specify error or something?

Comment: so API gateway doesn't seem to offer any integration with private service connect unlike services like CloudSQL. API gateway refers to the OpenAPI spec file to figure out which backends to use. Apart from the spec file, I couldn't find any option to enable the use of a private connection.

Comment: yes you are right  because the Google API gateways exist only for serverless product and is intended to be use only against serverless backends(s). It is possible to configure it against public IP’s that are hosted on our Google backends because they leverage the same x-google-backend configuration key-value pairs in the openapi.yaml for API Gateway.

Comment: but, more niche features like authorization on behalf of backend services, or limiting access to backed services hosted on non-serverless platforms like GKE are currently not supported. a possible workaround could be to set up endpoints directly with your GKE cluster you, this documentation could help you [first](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine#python), [second](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method), [third](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/endpoints/getting-started/openapi.yaml)

Comment: yup, API gateway is still in beta and lacks these features. I did end up setting up cloud endpoints for my use case and realized that it is a self-managed version of API gateway and eventually will come under the umbrella of API gateway. Thanks for referring the relevant docs here :)

Comment: hello again I edited my answer, so the information is clear, also can you confirm that this information was useful so other users can see it as well?

Comment: yup, have confirmed the same.